# как правильно сверстать вот такой блок

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Научите верстать.Знаю что нужно применить table. Но у меня как то коряво все это выглядит.

Comment: Таблицей можно сделать, но нельзя. Сейчас таблицами верстать нужно только таблицы и письма, отправляемые на email. Какие требования по поддержке браузеров? Можно сверстать флексом или обычными блоками. Ещё покажите как у вас это коряво выглядит.

Comment: Это верстается довольно просто обычными div-ами на float-ах, нечего выдумывать здесь табличную верстку и тем более приплетать flexbox. И судя по всему это блок табов.

Comment: Лучше коряво, чем никак. Добавьте свой код.

Answer (score 1):

Я подобные блоки верстаю с помощью `column-count`

```css
.block{
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
.item{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="block">
    <li class="item">text line 1</li>
    <li class="item">text line 2</li>
    <li class="item">text line 3</li>
    <li class="item">text line 4</li>
    <li class="item">text line 5</li>
    <li class="item">text line 6</li>
</ul>
```

Поддержка у свойства IE10+

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block-tab-menu {
  width: 660px;
  min-height: 240px;
  outline: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

.menu-block {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-block li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  width: 165px;
  margin-right: -6px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 48px;
}

.menu-block a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: #758791;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.menu-block .active a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #8bc34a;
  color: #000;
}

.sub-menu-block {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
}

.sub-menu-block li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 250px;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.sub-menu-block a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: #758791;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sub-menu-block a span {
  color: green;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-tab-menu">
  <ul class="menu-block">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Item Features</a></li>
    <ul class="sub-menu-block">
      <li><a href="#"><span>&#62;</span>Printing and typesetting industry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>&#62;</span>Bhen an unknown printe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>&#62;</span>Handard dummy text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>&#62;</span>Desktop publishing software</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>&#62;</span>Bhen an unknown printe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>&#62;</span>Printing and typesetting industry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>&#62;</span>Bhen an unknown printe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>&#62;</span>Handard dummy text</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Comments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rewiews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Рецепт**

Для приготовления меню потребуется:

- 1 - div
- 2 - маркированных списка ul
- несколько элементов li

Внутри блока `.block-tab-menu` создаем меню `.menu-block`, внутри которого создаем дочернее меню `.sub-menu-block`. Как видно таблица не понадобилась.

Comment: Тег <span> можно убрать и применить иконошрифт с иконкой.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!